# how to prevent adding duplicate node in kendo-knockout treeview

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, treeview

## Prevent adding duplicate node in kendo-knockout tree

```
    Before adding nodetext to root node i need to check the existance of nodetext
if same nodetext present then show valid message
OR get child node of selected rood(node)
```

```
$("#appendNode").click(function () {
                            var selectedNode = treeview.select();
                            var nodeText = $("#txtnode").val();//node to insert
                            if (selectedNode.length == 0)
                               selectedNode = null;
                            if (nodeText == null || nodeText == "")
                               return;
                             /*  if(nodetext is exist in childnode of selectedNode)
                                      valid message
                                 else
                                     add node to root
                              */
                            treeview.append({ text: nodeText }, selectedNode);
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filterByText method to find out that nodetext is already exist 
 ``http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [
        { text: "foo" },
        { text: "bar" }
    ]
    });

    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    // find the node with text "foo"
    var foo = treeview.findByText("foo");
    console.log(foo);
</script>
```

Also use findByUid if you use id for treeview data